# Sending an email once a form is submitted using smtp and gmail in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, email, smtp

I'm trying to receive an email once my form is submitted on my webpage. At the moment it submits fine without any errors but I don't receive the email. Does anyone know what code I have to add in the code behind page to make this work?

Here is the html;

```
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <br />
        <table>            
            <tr>
                <td  style="align-items:center">
                    Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName"
                                    runat="server"
                                    Columns="40"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  style="align-items:center">
                    email:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail"
                                    runat="server"
                                    Columns="40"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>



            <!-- Message -->
            <tr>
                <td style="align-items:center">
                    What are you looking for?
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage"
                                    runat="server"
                                    Columns="40"
                                    Rows="6"
                                    TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td  style="align-items:center">
                    What would you be willing to pay for this app?</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPay"
                                    runat="server"
                                    Columns="40"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Submit -->
            <tr style="align-items:center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"
                        onclick="btnSubmit_Click" /><br />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Results -->
            <tr style="align-items:center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

this is the code behind;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Telluswhatyouwant : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            //Create the msg object to be sent
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            //Add your email address to the recipients
            msg.To.Add("ronan.byrne@mhlabs.net");

//Send the msg
            client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: share your full code for mail sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly working code for localhost where mailing option is enabled. You can change the port number.fromWho, toWho are mailing addresses in string format (ie: david@yahoo.com)

```
    string sMailServer = "127.0.0.1";

    MailMessage MyMail = new MailMessage();
    MyMail.From = fromWho;
    MyMail.To = toWho;
    if (toCC != "" || toCC != null)
    {
        MyMail.Cc = toCC;
    }
    if (toBCC != "" || toBCC != null)
    {
        MyMail.Bcc = toBCC;
    }

    MyMail.Subject = Subject;
    MyMail.Body = Body;
    //MyMail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    MyMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = sMailServer;
    try
    {

        SmtpMail.Send(MyMail);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and make sure you are using valid login credential and you have proper internet connection:

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.Subject = "Your Subject";
 mail.From = new MailAddress("senderMailAddress");
 mail.To.Add("ReceiverMailAddress");
 mail.Body = "Hello! your mail content goes here...";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
 smtp.EnableSsl = true;
 NetworkCredential netCre = 
                  new NetworkCredential("SenderMailAddress","SenderPassword" );
 smtp.Credentials = netCre;

 try
  {
     smtp.Send(mail);                
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {   
    // Handle exception here 

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have configured your `client` Object. Give complete detail.

Then go through the following post answered by me. You should configure your `SmtpClient` properly.

[How to send email in ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp/18326814#18326814)