# Use Email Address that is stored in SQL Table to use in difference aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, email, visual-studio-2012

I want to use the email address that is stored in a SQL Table (Memberships), the one created by Visual Studio when you build a website. NB: Not an MVC Site, just a regular webform

Say for instance, If i am logged into the website, with my username and password --> it recognises me as the user X. Bearing in mind user X has a user name, password, email address.

Now, during the application i want to press a submit button which sends an email BUT i want it to use user X's email address as the FROM address.

Part of submit button:

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(nameddl.Text);
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("User X's email address");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
```

Example of SQL Table:

```
ID   --  Username   --  Email Address  --  Password

1    --  UserX      -- userx@x.com     --  password
```

I am struggling to find a way to insert a variable or something that contain the logged in user's email address in this line without manually typing in their address -->

```
 MailAddress from = new MailAddress("User X's email address");
```

Can anyone show me a way to do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
var userEmail = currentUser.Email;
```

See [*Membership.GetUser*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(userEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be work for sessions ;)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

```
Session["mail"] = new MailAddress("...");
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! i tried sessions also, but had no success!