# Convert HTML invoice and Email

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax, css

i am developing an ERP.  i have html invoice and  need as  email. The question is  constructing  invoice in jquery & ajax, i need to convert PDF and mail that invoice, please help me regarding this!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour ..Welcome to SO , A good place to start with

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to concentrate on one item at a time. This is just a head start of your requirement.

1. Build the Invoice :  Integrate an editor just like this or you can get from [CkEditer](http://ckeditor.com/)(If want  your user to change the content/design)
2. Generate  the PDF : Grab the html from the Editer and send that to create the PDF (you can use [itextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) or [EO.PDf](http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/Pdf/Default.aspx)

   `//Code to convert an Url or HTML file to PDF. The following code writes  output to a file. You can 
   //also write output to a Stream, a PdfPage, or a PdfDocument object
   HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(urlOrHtmlFile, outputFileName);`
3. Attach the generated PDF, and [Email.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp)
   [Email with Attachment](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/832559/Sending-an-E-Mail-With-Attachment-Using-ASP-Net-MV)

Check and change your spec as required.
Ask Questions  with specific scenario on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) to get help on that.