# IEmailSender - library

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What library i need for IEmailSender in asp.net mvc 5 ?

This is how code looks like:

```
public class PasswordResetHelper
{
     private IEmailSender emailSender;    
    public PasswordResetHelper(IEmailSender emailSenderParam) 
    {        
        emailSender = emailSenderParam;    
    }    
    public void ResetPassword() 
    {        
        // ...call interface methods to configure e-mail details... 
        emailSender.SendEmail();    
    } 
}
```

I take that code from a book for mvc 5 but it didn't work.
What i do wrong ?

P.S. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Perhaps you need to read the rest of the book?

Comment: which book are you referring to?

Comment: This is the book : http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Experts-Voice-ASP-Net/dp/1430265299/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438346418&sr=8-1&keywords=asp.net+mvc+5

Comment: I belive that it is "Pro ASP.NET MVC 5" by Adam Freeman. Anyway, it's just a code sample to show you how to build your application structure, it is not tied to any specific library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a piece of code that will send emails for you. This isn't in that book.

The code you show is in a chapter that's titled "Building Loosely Coupled Components":

> [...] one of [the] most important features of the MVC pattern is that it enables **separation of concerns**. [...] A **simple example** will help put things in context. **If** we were writing a component called `MyEmailSender` to send e-mail messages [...]

Emphasis mine.

They're trying to teach you the concept of building good, maintainable, testable software through separation of concerns and dependency injection.

If you're just looking for copy-pasteable code to implement an email sending class, you've bought the wrong book.

If all you're looking for is code to send an email, see [How to send email in ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp).

Comment: I don't look for copy-pastebale code, I just want to see how that code work and i understand more easy if i try it not just read it

Comment: There is no code. The implementation of `MyEmailSender` is not in the book. They're trying to explain a concept.