# Sending E-mail through Asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote this code and It's not working

```
try
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add("XXXXXXX@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("XXXXXXX@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "ASP.NET e-mail test";
        mailMessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        Response.Write("E-mail sent!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
    }
```

I Took this code from asp.net tutorials.  It is not working for me.

I get an error:

> Failed to send e-mail

Appreciate any help

Comment: yo we got your mail now. That being said, stack trace please.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: any error messages?apart from  'Failed to send e-mail'

Comment: Couple of things: 1) You have not specified the Port Number. 2) You have not set the SMTP credentials.

Comment: one issue may be gmail does not allow their mail account to be spoofed.  In the past when I've used .net code to send through my gmail account, I got an error message from googles smtp server.  try another account that may give you permissions

Comment: @userDEV I think This is it ... thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21347331/298336

Answer (score 0):

Pass the port number .

```
new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
```