# i can't find CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} or ms-outlook on DCOM

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, outlook, dcom

I received the following error  when I tried to send email from web application  although  it was working good before  , Do you have any idea about that ? and it working in  the debug mode of visual studio but is not working through the IIS right now.

“Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.”

As per my understanding  this error is related  to access denied  of IIS  to outlook object  but i try  to find solution  for that in google : the solution is to make permission  to IIS-USRs account for the outlook but I don’t know how to do that 
 So, i try to find MS-OUTLOOK on dcom  to add IIS-USRS but i can't find it 
 could you tell me the exact name of outlook on DCOM.

My Code as below

```
        Dim ol As New Outlook.Application()
        Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
        Try
            Dim fdMail As Outlook.MAPIFolder
            ns = ol.GetNamespace(MAPI)
            ns.Logon(, , True, True)


            'creating a new MailItem object
            Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
            'gets defaultfolder for my Outlook Outbox
            fdMail = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox)
            'assign values to the newMail MailItem
            newMail = fdMail.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
            newMail.Subject = RecordtypeDropDownList.Text +  Notification
            newMail.Body = You got  + RecordtypeDropDownList.Text +   for  + CategoryDropdownList.Text

            'newMail.To = EmaildropDownlistEM.Text ' we will pass the email from record missbonus point table in the final stage

            newMail.To = Mid(EmaildropDownlistEM.Text, (EmaildropDownlistEM.Text.IndexOf(, )) + 2, 10) + . + Left(EmaildropDownlistEM.Text, EmaildropDownlistEM.Text.IndexOf(, ))


            newMail.CC = xxxxxxxxx

            newMail.SaveSentMessageFolder = fdMail
            newMail.Send()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
```

Comment: You should not really be using Outlook Automation to send email from an ASP.Net environment, what's wrong with the frameworks email classes?

Comment: thanks for your reply,So what your suggestion if i have outlook account on the same server of IIS and i want to let it to send emails for asp.net app

Comment: Do you need outlook for some reason? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: yes,1- because was very simple to configure it in visualbasic 2-when i tried the gmail  i found some times is not working if the internet provider closes the gmail port will not working

Comment: Can you show your code please? What assemblies or APIs are you using?

Comment: thanks for your  help my code as above

Comment: import System.Net.Mail
import System.Net
import Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
 i think you need that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Outlook (or any other Office app) in a service (such as IIS). In case of Exchange, you can use EWS. In all other cases, using straight SMTP is probably the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Could tell me How to get SMTP for free

Comment: A component that wraps SMTP? Or an SMTP server?