# How to write mail Function using C#?

Tags: c#, forms, email

I had created the bootstrap contact form in a website. can anyone help me to write the code for mail function in C#,That yje user fill the form ,when the user clicks submit button,the details must sent to admin's mail.

Here is the code for bootstrap form:

```
<form class="form form-container">
            <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <label for="Name">Name <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" required>
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                    <label for="Company">Company</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="company" type="text" >
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <br>
                    <label for="Gender">Gender <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="gender" required>
                        <option value="">Select option</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <br>
                    <label for="Email">E-Mail <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <br>
                    <label for="Phone">Phone <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <br>
                    <label for="Subject">Subject <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required>
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <br>
                    <label for="Message">Message <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="message" required></textarea>
                <br>
            </span>
            <span class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-success" value="Send message"><br><br><br><br>   
            </span>
        </form>
```

Comment: Send e-mail via SMTP using C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Smtpclient to send the email from your code behind action
Example is at [How to send email in ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Sample code is

```
try
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add("your.own@mail-address.com");
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("another@mail-address.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "ASP.NET e-mail test";
        mailMessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.your-isp.com");
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        Response.Write("E-mail sent!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have no idea in c#, I have a knowledge in php. Could you tell me what are the steps to do after written the code for form.

Comment: Better to follow some basic C# tutorial prior. Also i will suggests you to follow asp.net tutorial as well

Comment: thanks for your info