# How to remove outlook alert dialog box in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application in asp.net C# which sends some mails to recipients on button click automatically but each time an alert box appears asking for confirmation. How to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Automating Office from ASP.Net is not supported or recommended, the issue above is only one small example of why.  There are other methods to send e-mail such as SmtpClient, is there a reason you are not using one?

Comment: ASP.NET means web site. What is that *web site* trying to do with your mailbox anyway? It doesn't need *outlook* to make an SMTP call. If the application is only meant to run on your machine, your account and access your Outlook *why is it a web site* in the first place?

Comment: Have a squiz at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18326814/34092