# SSIS - how to send an Email as a Destination in a dataflow?

Tags: email, ssis

I need to send a daily report to my boss with analyzed data.
the data flow works just fine, but instead of the flat file destination, i want to send him an email with the data in the body.

I searched for it all over, and found how to send it through "for each loop" but it sends the output as a single row through multiple emails.

I need the **WHOLE data** in one mail.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native SSIS componentry to help you with this. However, you can build it out of the existing pieces.

You can use a `Script Component` as a destination and then accumulate all the values there and then in the PostExecute portion (which would indicate you have received all the rows) use .NET to [send the email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18326738/181965).

If you're doing no transformation logic in your data flow, investigate whether (assuming SQL Server) the DBAs have configured `[sp_send_dbmail][1]` You can provide a query as a parameter to that procedures. You can also specify whether you want the results in line or as an attachment.

If you're going the attachment route, write the results to a text file and then use the native Send Mail Task and simply include it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

1. Create a string variable called MyMessageBody
2. In your data flow, create a transform script component and add
   MyMessageBody variable to the ReadWriteVariables list.
3. In your script component have the following script (notice that the
   idea would be to concatenate the data from each row to the
   MyMessageBody variable as the rows are going through the script
   component).

   ```
   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
   public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
   {


       private String _emailBody = "";


       public override void PostExecute()
       {
           base.PostExecute();
           Variables.MyMessageBody = _emailBody;

       }

       public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
       {

              // define all the columns you need to return in your email
              // I am assuming that you are returning two columns here
               var Var1 = Row.Var1_IsNull ? "NULL": Row.Var1;
               var Var2 = Row.Var2_IsNull ? "NULL" : Row.Var2;

             // concatenate data rows as they are going through the component
               _emailBody += String.Format(@"Var1: {0}
                            Var2: {1}",
                   Var1, Var2
                   );

       }

   }
   ```
4. Finally, add a "Send Mail Task" and use an Expression for the
   MessageSource reading the variable that you just constructed in the
   data flow (MyMessageBody).

Comment: thank you! but i get errors in the script: _myKey- "the name does not exist.  var1_isnull- "Input0Buffer does not contain definition for var1_isnull. var1- "Input0Buffer does not contain definition for var1 (same as ver2). HELP...

Comment: @AviadAmar Var1, Var2 are heuristic names I used for illustration purposes. You need to replace them with your actual column names in the data flow. So if you have two columns (Region, Amount) then you need to replace all references for Var1 with  Region and Var2 with amount.