# Cannot send email using SmtpClient in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtpclient, servicepoint

I want to send email in ASP.NET MVC website but it doesn't work.

I think the problem is with this exception here

'client.ServicePoint.Address' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' with type System.Uri {System.NotSupportedException}.

after the code

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 25)
```

In this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint.address?view=netcore-3.1, it says the exception is due to "The ServicePoint is in host mode." which I have no idea.

Could anyone explain it and tell me how to resolve?

Thanks,

Comment: The true issue is the port number I'm using is not correct.... should use 587...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET, SMTP settings has its own config section (beneath the system.net element) in the `app.config` and `web.config` file:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network host="smtp.office365.com" port="25" enableSsl="true" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

You can read more about SMTP [here](https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/)

And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18326814/8289603) in the community may help you.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is the port number I'm using is incorrect....

Comment: Perfect! I will update this answer with your solution :>