# ASP.NET / IIS 7 - Authenticate against an Active Directory using a Principal

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, active-directory, principal

My current application uses the [`PrincipalContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.aspx) class to authenticate a default user (filled in in the **Web.config** dedicated section) against a LDAP (and more precisely an Active Directory):

```
ldapContext = new PrincipalContext(AdContextType, AdHost, AdContainer, 
                                   ContextOptions.SimpleBind,
                                   AdDefaultUser, AdDefaultPassword)
```

This authentication then allows to search for any other user (via `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ldapContext, username)`). BUT I have to change this, since having a user in clear in the **Web.config** is not acceptable for my client. OK, I can understand that :-))

So I have several solutions:

- manage to encrypt the corresponding part of the **Web.config** (the `membership` part, with `providers` etc)
- use the account from the application pool of the IIS 7 on which the application is deployed. This implies to retrieve a Principal from IIS (I guess this point should not be so hard), then use it for authentication against the AD; but I cound not find any method for that, neither via the `PrincipalContext` class not via the [`ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) one.

Do you know how to manage any of these 2 solutions, or do you think of any other ?

Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not the username is your problem, more the password? As far as I can tell the second solution want work. There is no way that I know to do this.

For the first solution you can encrypt the username and the password and store the encrypted values in a string. After loading you will need to decrypt the strings. But your solution will not be safe against disassemble.

You should also think about if you need a high security implementation then you may store the encryption key in a secure store. Then you will be saver against disassemble.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is the password: I guess there is no way to get the password from a Principal (basic security). Ok, I'll have a look at encryption.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! A good way to encrypt is via an IIS tool which is well described in [this other SO subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134658/problem-encrypting-membership-element-in-web-config).